# Why does the m2e plugin build to a WEB-INF/classes in the target folder for a maven jar project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

Since I am packaging a jar (i.e. Maven jar project), I don't know why m2e insists on setting the Eclipse project's source folder's output to write to target/**WEB-INF**/classes.  I tried changing it to point to build/classes, but as soon as I do a `Maven -> Update Project` it changes it back.
Why? Am I missing a project level setting?

Update: Added pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.mycompany.ta.wh</groupId>
        <artifactId>sales-master-pom</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>0.0.18</version> -->
        <version>[0.0.1,2.0.0)</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>amq2gcppubsub</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.33-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Amq2GcpPubsub</name>
    <description>Subscribes to an ActiveMQ queue and publishes to a Google Cloud Platform Pubsub Topic.</description>
    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git://github.mycompany.com/DNA/amq2gcppubsub</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://github.mycompany.com/DNA/amq2gcppubsub</developerConnection>
        <url>https://github.mycompany.com/DNA/amq2gcppubsub</url>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
    </scm>

    <properties>
        <!-- DEPENDENCY VERSIONS -->
        <javabatch.version>3.1</javabatch.version>
        <activemq.version>5.8.0</activemq.version>
        <!--  Override master pom because conflicts with activemq's slf4j version -->
        <slf4j.api.version>1.6.6</slf4j.api.version> 
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>1.6.6</version>  -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency conf="runtime" org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-log4j12" rev="1.7.6"> -->
<!--            <exclude module="log4j" /> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mycompany.ta.aa</groupId>
            <artifactId>JavaBatch</artifactId>
            <version>${javabatch.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency> <!-- Required by JavaBatch -->
            <groupId>com.mycompany.ss.sh</groupId>
            <artifactId>THDDAO_TaAaDistributedBatch</artifactId>
            <version>2.15</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
            <version>1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-pubsub</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mycompany.ta.aa</groupId>
            <artifactId>THDDAO</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
            <version>${activemq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mycompany.ta.aa</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomarch</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.27</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Check the project facets: Right-click > Properties > Project Facets. Do you have Dynamic Web Module selected?

Comment: Is your packaging really `jar`, or is it `war`?

Comment: And your pom.xml looks like?

Comment: @tunaki Under Project Facets it says: "This project is not configured to use project facets..."

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I added the pom.xml

Comment: @kdgregory yes, it is jar not war.  See attached pom.xml

Comment: I think your easiest solution is to delete and re-import this project. There's nothing in this POM that should lead to the creation of a WEB-INF directory, unless it's in the parent, so my best guess is that something changed between the time you created the project and now. No idea what that might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this was happening was because I had this "outputDirectory" tag in the `<build>` section of the parent pom.

```
<!-- for hot reload of the web application -->
<outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes
</outputDirectory>
```

As soon as I removed that, the Maven Update removed "WEB-INF" from the .classpath output directories.